# PHP friendly URL's issue

Tags: php, html

I can get friendly URL working on localhost but not on my web server. Any ideas.

```
$countryfriendly = GenerateUrl ($country_name_bread);

$regionfriendly = GenerateUrl ($region_name_bread);

$townfriendly = GenerateUrl ($town_name_bread);

$titlefriendly = GenerateUrl ($fetch_property["property_name"]);
```

Above is taken from breadcrumb and put into button below (URL friendly button)

```
<!--<a href="/' .$countryfriendly .'/' .$regionfriendly. '/' .$townfriendly. '/' . $titlefriendly . '/' .md5($id).'" button type="submit" class="btn btn-  primary">MORE DETAILS</button></a>-->
```

Original button

```
<a href="'.$WS_PATH.'/members/property_details.php?q='.md5($id).'&he=act"    button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">MORE DETAILS</button></a>
```

Web page source code shows

```
<!--<a href="/portugal/algarve/lagos/name/819f46e52c25763a55cc642422644317" button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">MORE DETAILS</button></a>-->
```

Its correct but click it and it goes nowhere? Its commented out as you can see atm.

The original works fine

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/members/details.php?q=819f46e52c25763a55cc642422644317&he=act" button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">MORE DETAILS</button></a>
```

The friendly URL button link only works on localhost? It doesn’t work on my webserver… It shows correctly but goes nowhere when clicked?? error is "404 page not found".....

Options +FollowSymLinks All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

for town

```
RewriteRule ^continent/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).php/(.*)  /maps.php?contifolder=$1&countryfolder=$2&statefolder=$3&gettown=$4&pg=$5 [L]
```

for town

```
RewriteRule ^continent/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).php  /maps.php?contifolder=$1&countryfolder=$2&statefolder=$3&gettown=$4 [L]
```

for states/region

```
RewriteRule ^continent/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).php  /maps.php?contifolder=$1&countryfolder=$2&getstate=$3 [L]
```

for countries

```
RewriteRule ^continent/(.*)/(.*).php  /maps.php?contifolder=$1&getcountry=$2 [L]
```

for continents

```
RewriteRule ^continent/(.*).php  /maps.php?getconti=$1 [L]
```

Anyone?

Comment: try to use the full URL, including http:// and the domain name, see if that works

Comment: You completely forgot to post how those "friendly URLs" (how you call them) are processed. What are your RewriteRules?

Comment: added to post above..

Comment: A seemingly silly comment, but your two buttons call different files. One being property_details.php and the other details.php. Is this intentional? Otherwise the 404 is a no-brainer :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake they are both "property_details.php"

Comment: Perhaps .htaccess is different on server and localhost?

Comment: when i use the friendly URL button, I get this - Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent, it was hiding behind  a header.

Comment: The (warning session start) error only appears if I use the friendly URL button, as above. When using the normal button there are no errors?